# ibm cloud side menu: cannot retrieve 'Connection Security' nor 'Devices'

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, iot

I'm configuring the IoT solution as explained via https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/gather-visualize-analyze-iot-data.html#gather-visualize-and-analyze-iot-data. At step 3 of section 'Create IoT Platform' I should go to menu Security and then Connection Security to choose TLS option. However, I am not able to retrieve 'Connection Security' (and also 'Devices' I'm not able to find). Is there anyone who could give me an indication where to retrieve this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From left menu choose Security:
[image]

Then click on the pencil from the right of "Connection Security"
[image]

Choose TLS Optional from Security Level drop down
[image]

Finally, click on Save from top right.

Comment: Hello Idan, thanks for your feedback. The point is that the menu I have is like:

Comment: https://console.bluemix.net/security-advisor/#/overview. Could you pls send me the link to the screen in your first picture? That would be helpful I think.

Comment: @Franc the link you sent points to different security settings, and that is to IBM Cloud. What you need is actually on the IoT Service. You can either launch it from the IBM Cloud console by using the Launch button after you select the IoT Service, or you can login via https://internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/

Comment: Hello Idan - thanks a lot for this direction - now I'm able to continue!

Comment: please accept the answer so that others can benefit